# Add method of adding paragraphs to formatting page

Tags: feature-request, markdown, help

I just found another post where a user is using single line break to create separate lines / paragraphs. This of course won't do anything in Markdown; two line breaks or a `<p>` tag are required. So I wanted to point out how to add paragraphs / sections by forwarding the user to [the help / formatting page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). However, to my surprise nothing is said about this, while creating sections in a post is one of the best tips to enhance readability.

Could somebody please put this somewhere on top of the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow formatting pages? Maybe put the trick to insert line breaks [space][space][enter] right below it so they are grouped together (and code blocks / comments below that). That way new users don't need to wonder what happened to their line breaks... at least if they took the time to read the formatting hints.

Comment: Mods: I might be willing to rewrite the pages for SE and SO to be more comprehensible to users if asked nicely. Currently it is written OK, but the ordering and such is a bit of a hodge-podge and not really user-centric.

Comment: What is not ok in the linebreak section of the help/formatting page ? (I mean: what in this sentence is unclear: "New paragraphs only occur when there is a blank line. A single carriage does not create a new paragraph." ?)

Comment: Huh, OK, so that's in the paragraph for line breaks, and without any example. OK, so I completely overlooked it for that reason, and I guess that's then also what is wrong with it. Besides that the wording ... "carriage" ... typewriters anyone?

Comment: and btw SO has a different wording indeed, so there's probably something to do network wide